# Replace a special character with a new line within same row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

We have a character | in one of the columns in a pandas dataframe which needs to be replaced with a new line within the same columns.

I tried using *replace* which doesn't seem to give the expected output.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['sample || text | needs replacement'] , columns=['text'])
df.text.str.replace('|' , '\n')

# Gives sample \n\n text \n needs replacement

# Expected output 

"""sample 

text 
needs replacement
"""
print(len(df['text'])) #1
```

Comment: Since pandas `0.25.0` we have a new function for this called `explode`, you can use: `df['text'].str.split('|').explode()`

Comment: Thanks @Erfan , Do we have any other methods to tackle this problem with pandas 0.23.0

Comment: There are some custom functions in the linked answer which you can use. But I would recommend to update your pandas and simply use the line of code which I provided

Comment: Thanks @Erfan , explode() is creating multiple rows.  Is it possible to have new lines within the same row?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: We have requirement to have so.

Comment: @Erfan , could you please remove this as duplicate.